# Back to Menu issue

Tags: lua, coronasdk, physics

I nave a little qiestion on my code,
When i stops the physics engine how it can be restarted?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/physicsSetup/index.html

Start / Pause / Stop

The following functions start, pause, and stop the physics simulation:

```
physics.start() — either instantiates or resumes the simulation (if paused). You must start the physics simulation before calling any other physics functions in this guide.
physics.pause() — pauses the physics simulation.
physics.stop() — this is treated as a request to "destroy" the physics world. If you merely want to pause the physics engine, use physics.pause().
```

Is this what you were looking for?